# sendMediaGroup telegram PHP

Tags: php, sdk, telegram

I am using telegram library

> php telegram bot sdk

And I want to send some photos in message using **sendMediaGroup**

Like this:

```
$reply = "*photos*";
$telegram->sendMediaGroup([
     'chat_id' => $chat,
     'media' => [
      ['type' => 'photo', 'media' => 'attach://photo1' ],
      ['type' => 'photo', 'media' => 'attach://photo2' ],
  ],
     'photo1' => InputFile::create(file_get_contents("https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/newbot/screens/ctry/en1.jpg")),
     'photo2' => InputFile::create(file_get_contents("https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/newbot/screens/ctry/en2.jpg")),
     'caption'=> $reply,
     'parse_mode' => 'markdown'
     ]);
```

I used without **json_encode** and **file_get_contents**, but it doesn't worked too

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use that library? Here's the normal solution:

```
$token = '   TOKEN   ';
$website = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token;
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
$message = $update['message']['text'];
$id = $update['message']['from']['id'];
$name = $update['message']['from']['first_name'];
$surname = $update['message']['from']['last_name'];
$username = $update['message']['from']['username'];

function sendPhoto($id, $photo, $text = null){
    GLOBAL $token;
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token."/sendPhoto?chat_id=$id&photo=$photo&parse_mode=HTML&caption=".urlencode($text);
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

I also put there some useful variable and the chance to put a caption (don't give that parameter if you don't want one)

Comment: I use that library because I like it, and it's much more convenient for me to use it than a code like yours

Comment: I don't think it is more convenient, however, just opinions, if you want I can help you in this way, it is much easier to send every type of messages, including text, sticker, photo, photo with caption, video, document etc. (also adding buttons via callback query). If you prefer your library just wait for someone other that likes it to help you, I'm sorry

Comment: No, bro, I'm very thankful that you helped me, I only said my opinion about this library

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, you're welcome